# Implement X-RateLimit-Limit with wso2

Tags: rest, wso2

I need WSO2 to return at every REST API request the following 3 ratelimit headers:

- X-RateLimit-Limit: actual application limit
- X-RateLimit-Remaining: remaining requests
- X-RateLimit-Reset: seconds to the moment of reset

Is there a plugin/mediator allowing this?
Which HTTP headers does WSO2 notify clients the remaining quota metrics?

Thanks@all!

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. The throttling is managed by APIM traffic manager and it processes the events asynchronously and publishes only the throttling decision back to the gateway. Hence, the gateway has no way of obtaining the values of the above headers.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @thilinistg for your reply!

When the request is 429'd, the retry-after information is passed together with the decision, right? 
When the request is allowed, is the gateway notified in some way, or there's a silence-acceptance poliy?